# Emulator not present in android studio in mac

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I am using android studio 2.2.1 on macbook air with jdk-8u91.
My android studio is running fine but there is no emulator shown and no mobile app present in "Design" window.
only "API 24" is shown. I was suggested to add API 22 which shows the mobile app but after installing "jdk 8" there is only API 24 Present.
I have been to module settings but only MinsdkVersion present is 15(Android 6X(N)), it does not show any other version available.
Please tell , how to run emulator and mobile app.

Comment: The preview window and the emulator are two separate things. Which one is the problem?

Comment: Do you have updated SDK manager?